# Show result JSON Parse to Custom Listview with Section

Tags: android, json, listview

i already success to Parsing my API on debug. so, i want to show some data to listview, but my listview still default with hardcode like this :

```
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new String("Persiapanasas Lahan"));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(1 ,"Informasi Tantangan dan Kelengkapan Data", R.drawable.statuscolor));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(2,"Artikel Manajemen Lahan",R.drawable.statuscolor));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(3, "Video Proses Budidaya Cabai", R.drawable.statuscolor));
    list.add(new String("Pembersihan Rumput"));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(4 ,"Video Pengendalian Gulma dengan Herbisida", R.drawable.statuscolororange));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(5 ,"Informasi Rekomendasi saat Pengendalian", R.drawable.statuscolorgray));
    list.add(new timelinedetail_modul(6, "Artikel Pengendalian Gulma", R.drawable.statuscolorgray));

    listView.setAdapter(new adapterListview_detail(this, list));
```

and this is adapter listview

```
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view == null) {
        switch (getItemViewType(i)){
            case JUDUL:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_detail, null);
                break;
            case HEADER:
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_detail_header, null);
                break;
        }
    }

    switch (getItemViewType(i)){
        case JUDUL:


            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            TextView judul = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.judul);
            TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

            System.out.println(i);
            judul.setText(((timelinedetail_modul)list.get(i)).getJudul());
            number.setText((String.valueOf(((timelinedetail_modul) list.get(i)).getNumber())));
            image.setImageResource(((timelinedetail_modul)list.get(i)).getImage());

        break;
        case HEADER:

            TextView header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);

            header.setText((String.valueOf(list.get(i))));

            break;
    }

    return view;


}
```

i build this with hardcode listview, so how to use my JSON parsing to show in listview with section

UPDATE :

my json parse

```
` if(response.code() == 200){
                try {

                    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray array = responseObject.getJSONArray("sections");

                    for (int i= 0 ; i<array.length() ; i ++) {

                        //sections
                        JSONObject sections = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nameSection = sections.getString("name");
                        String description = sections.getString("description");

                        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();


                            //topics
                            JSONArray topics = new JSONArray(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("topics"));

                            for (int j = 0; j <topics.length(); j++) {

                                String order = topics.getJSONObject(j).getString("order");
                                String nameTopics = topics.getJSONObject(j).getString("name");

                            }


                    }

                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }`
```

example my JSON :

`"sections": [
    {
      "name": "Section 1",
      "description": "Persiapan Lahan",
      "createdAt": {
        "timestamp": 1487758752,
        "iso": "2017-02-22T10:19:12.264Z"
      },
      "id": "5ae81880-f8e8-11e6-9d03-95a25b24350d",
      "topics": [
        {
          "order": 1,
          "name": "Informasi Tantangan dan Kelengkapan Data Petani",
          "description": "Informasi Tantangan dan Kelengkapan Data Petani",
          "createdAt": {
            "timestamp": 1491551644,
            "iso": "2017-04-07T07:54:04.668Z"
          },
          "id": "5ef38ad0-1b67-11e7-be66-8ff601a0bedd",
          "isCompleted": true,
          "status": "completed",
          "completedAt": {
            "timestamp": 1492489573,
            "iso": "2017-04-18T04:26:13.976Z"
          },`

Comment: Create a java class which demonstrates your objects in json file and set the properties during the parsing process. Then make a list of these objects and fill your list with them.

Comment: can you explain with example sir, sorry :( @nassertahani

Comment: If you place your JSON file I could explain it.

Comment: @nassertahani edited my question. i show my json file

Answer (score 0):

create a adapter with List (hardcode)

```
adapterListview_detail adapter = new adapterListview_detail(this, mList);
```

after parse Json , you should update your list (mList) and call :

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```